# positioning absolute div with in relative div to top of the screen

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a structure where there are many relative position `div` and inside them another `div` with `position: absolute`. Now I want to show this absolute position `div` on top left corner of screen, covering full screen for mobiles as overlay or dialog and user also able to scroll this, overlay or dialog can have forms. 
Fixed position is not solution.

How I can do that ?

```
<div class="relative">relative
<div class="absolute">absolute</div>
```

```
.relative {
    position:relative;
    margin-top:500px;
}
.absolute {
    position:absolute;
    top:0
}
```

**EDIT:** [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/A3N7V/)

People are very quick at down vote :) slow at suggestion

**Update:**

i can't use negative margin because i don't know the location of the relative div it can be anywhere in document and i can't make it direct child of the body

Comment: Can you not just move the absolutely-positioned divider's markup to make it a child of the `<body>` element?

Comment: No i can't do this i need only css solution

Comment: That is css only... @Yasir

Comment: @Rahil why you need code for this ? is not the question is clear enough ... here is the code <div style="position:relative; margin-top:500px;"><div style="position:absolute"></div></div> now align that absolute position on top ..

Comment: @Yasir Isn't it better to post this code in your question?

Comment: @RahilWazir Okay posted please check how i can position aboslute div to top left corner of screen .. it can be anywhere so fixed negative top is not solution for me

Comment: @JamesDonnelly i can't make it child of the body tag this needs to be under action tag from where it will be called.

Comment: @Yasir You need to understand 2 things with this: **1)** Once your question is **badly formatted**, **unclear** or even _I need this_ **without enough code**, your probabilities of being helped will vanish. **2)** Pissing up with this consequences (vote down or even none suggestion) will persist **UNTIL** you do something in your advantage...

Comment: @Fiskolin Thanks i will take care of it next time, i was trying to format but could't, now its formated bysomeone thanks for help, now where are they who down voted or ask for closing :)

Answer (score 1):

Just counter the positioning the `.relative` element has. Here your `.relative` element has a `margin-top` of 500px, so we can make our `.absolute` element appear 500px above by specifying a `top` of -500px:

```css
.absolute {
    position:absolute;
    top:-500px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/A3N7V/1/).

Comment: thanks good idea, but i can't get the margin or position of relative in css so i can counter the absolute position,and there can be many absolute position div with in relative at different positions other way i have to do it in js whereas i want to do it inside media query only.

Comment: @Yasir your question didn't mention any of this, any my answer answers the question you've asked...